# pass parameters in the url and return a data in the blade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble doing something that should be very simple.

I'm reading documentation, looking at posts and it just doesn't work.

I need to return parameters in the url and I need to return data to the blade.

I saw that with the redirect method you can return, which is the method I'm using. But I can't get the data on the blade

```
public function confirmEmail(Request $request)
    {
        // Step one
        // Check the recaptcha
        $recaptcha = GoogleReCaptchaV2::verifyResponse($request->input('g-recaptcha-response'))->isSuccess();
        
        if (!$recaptcha) {
            flash('Recaptcha invalido. Tente novamente')->error();

            return view('login');
            // return view('login', ['error' => 1, 'recaptcha' => $recaptcha]);
            // return redirect()->route('login', ['error' => 1, 'recaptcha' => $recaptcha]);
        }



        // Step two
        // Check email
        $email = $request->input('email');

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return view('login')->withErrors($validator->errors());
        }



        // Step three
        // Generate code and send mail
        $result = User::sendCode($email);

        if ($result['message'] != 'success') {
            flash($result['message'])->error();

            return view('login');
        }



        return redirect()->route('login', ['error' => 0, 'stepIndex' => 2, 'formType' => 'login', 'email' => $result['user']['email']])->with(['email', $result['user']['email']]);
    }
```

My blade

```
{{ session()->get('email') }}
{{ $email ?? null }}
```

Comment: The result variable returns some data, including data from a user. I checked and the variable is coming with the email data, so much so that the url appears.

Comment: `->with(['email', $result['user']['email']]);` that should be `->with(['email' => $result['user']['email']]);` (or `->with('email', $result['user']['email']);`), otherwise `session()->get('email')` won't be set.

Comment: Add `->withInput()` to your return.  - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: guys, it's not working :/

Comment: "it's not working" is not helpful at all... With the suggestions, what, _specifically_, isn't working? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75404246/edit) with the updated code and what's not working now.

Comment: Sorry. I ran tests with what you guys went through, but no results are shown on the blade. I'm using ```{{ session()->get('email') }}```, but nothing appears in the blade

Comment: Well, that might not be set, depending on which `return ...` you're hitting. `return view('login');` and `return view('login')->withErrors($validator->errors());` it will not be set. Also, I wouldn't mix returns like that... You should be doing a redirect or a view render, not both/either or.

Comment: I'm using this return ```return redirect()->route('login', ['error' => 0, 'stepIndex' => 2, 'formType' => 'login', 'email' => $result ['user']['email']])->with(['email', 'email']);```, I just made the modifications for testing in the 'with' method.

Comment: Stop doing this: `['email', 'email']`; that creates `session()->get('0')` and `session()->get('1')`, both of which would be the string `'email'`. Look closely at my first comment: `->with('email', 'email')` **OR** `->with(['email' => 'email'])`. You need to learn the difference between indexed and associative arrays in PHP, and how the `with()` functions works with 1 argument (an array) vs 2 arguments (2 strings). If you do that, _then_ you get `session()->get('email')`, which is the string `'email'`.

Comment: Unfortunately it still didn't work out. ```return redirect()->route('login', ['error' => 0, 'stepIndex' => 2, 'formType' => 'login', 'email' => $result['user']['email']])->with('email', $result['user']['email']);```

Comment: Your code [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUun3.png) [just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O19Jp.png) [for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuZt6.png). Defining a Route `/redirect`, that kicks me to `route('test', ['email' => 'test@test.com'])->with('email', 'test@test.com')` correctly displays the email in the url `/test?email=test@test.com`, and `dd(session()->get('email'));` returns `'test@test.com'`...

Comment: I need to show this in the html/blade. The way I'm trying to show it there, it's like this: ```{{ session()->get('email') }}```

Comment: Same code would work in a `.blade.php` file; the `session()` helper is available globally in Laravel.